# aws s3 php delete object on list of file

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody >
<?php foreach($objects as $object): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo basename($object['Key']); ?></td>
        <td>
            <form method='post' action='delete.php'>
                <?php
                    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
                        $s3->deleteObject([ 
                        'Bucket' => $bucket, 
                        'Key' => $object['Key']
                        ]);
                    }
                ?>
                <input type="submit" name="delete">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

HI. i have a table where i have the list of file with delete button. i want to delete a single file when i click the button beside it. but when im using **$object['Key']** variable, it delete all of the files that are listed. Maybe, because of the **foreach**.

Please help. :). im php noob.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: you have 1 form for each file
I think you need to pass the key in a different field (hidden maybe). Call it key_to_delete, and call ->deleteObject out of the foreach loop

Comment: the 'isset($_POST['delete']' will aways return true...

Answer (score 0):

The 'isset($_POST['delet‌​e']' will aways return true...
If you want to delete just one file, I sugest to call `$s3->deleteObject` outside of the foreach loop

```
<form method='post' action='delete.php'>
<input type="hidden" name="keyToDelete" value="<?php echo $object['Key']; ?>"
  <input type="submit" name="delete">
</form>
```

And the PHP try something like this

```
<?php
                if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
                    $s3->deleteObject([ 
                    'Bucket' => $bucket, 
                    'Key' => $_POST['keyToDelete']
                    ]);
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: it deletes the file when i click the submit button but i cant choose a file to delete. But you give me an idea. THANKS. :DDD.

Answer (score 0):

i just add checkboxes so i can choose a file to delete. :D

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th">File</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
    <?php foreach($objects as $object): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $object['Key']; ?>">
                <?php echo basename($object['Key']); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        @$check = $_POST['check'];

        endforeach; 

        if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {

            if(!empty($check)){

                foreach($check as $selected){

                    $s3->deleteObject([ 
                        'Bucket' => $bucket, 
                        'Key' => $selected
                        ]);
                }
            }else{
                echo 'Please select a file to delete';
            }
        }
                            ?>
                <input type="submit" name="delete">
            </form>
    </tbody>
</table>
```